# How can I use eager loading in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Supposing I have these 6 models such as

- User
- Profile
- Gender
- Country
- Prefecture
- Car

`User` has one `Profile`.
Then each `Profile` has those who are `gender_id`, `country_id`, and `prefecture_id`.
`User` also has many `Cars`

I'm stating asssociation just like this.

**models/user.rb**

```
has_one :profile
has_many :cars

scope :confirmed, where("sign_in_count != ?",0)
paginates_per 10
```

**models/profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :gender
belongs_to :country
belongs_to :prefecture
```

**models/gender.rb**

```
has_many :user_profile
```

**models/country.rb**

```
has_many :user_profile
```

**models/prefecture.rb**

```
has_many :user_profile
```

**models/car.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

And here's my question!
How can I fix my code in controller, and view?

This my current codes.

**CONTROLLER**

```
@users = User.confirmed.joins(:profile).page(params[:page]).order('profiles.total_point DESC')
```

**VIEW**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>  
        Username: <%= user.username %> <br />
        Total Point: <%= user.profile.total_point %> <br />
        Gender: <%= user.profile.gender.data %> <br />
        Country: <%= user.profile.country.data %> <br />
        Prefecture: <%= user.profile.prefecture.data %> <br />
        The number of the cars that the user owns: <%= user.cars.count %> <br />
    </tr>        
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why is gender a separate model? There won't be any new genders tomorrow. It should just be an attribute of user in my opinion.

Comment: because I want it as the number(integer) for summarizing performance purpose

Comment: So, just store `0` or `1` in your `gender` column and create a `GENDERS` constant to map your integer to a gender. `GENDERS = { 0 => 'male', 1 => 'female' }` It doesn't make sense to create a database table for data that never changes. Doing this will also make your queries easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

I think, you should try this approach:

```
@users = User.includes(:cars, profile: [:gender, :country, :prefecture]).confirmed.page(params[:page]).order('profiles.total_point DESC')
```

Does it work?

Comment: could you please customize my original code in controller? I can not figure out how to add your code to my original one

Comment: @users = User.includes(:cars, profile: [:gender, :country, :prefecture]).page(params[:page]).order('profiles.total_point DESC')

Does it work?

Comment: More details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations